# Realmのプライマリーキーのついたデータの追加

Tags: realm

AndroidでRealmを使っております。
Realmのドキュメントには以下のように、`createOrUpdate()`が書いてあるのですが、
どのように使うのでしょうか？またプライマリーキーのついたデータの重複があった場合、
例外が発生してしまいます。どのように例外の処理をすればよいでしょうか。例外が発生した場合
アプリが停止してしまいます。

> プライマリキーを指定したモデルについては、createOrUpdate()を使ってオブジェクトを作成または更新をすることができます。 このメソッドは、プライマリキーが一致するデータがすでに存在すれば、データを更新し、無ければ新しくオブジェクトを作成します。

Comment: `createOrUpdate()`というメソッドはありませんので、`copyToRealmOrUpdate()`の間違いでしょうか？`copyToRealmOrUpdate()`を使っていれば重複した場合は上書きされるので例外は起こりません。っもし例外が起こっているなら別の何かだと思います。この情報だけだとわからないので、どのようなコードでどこで例外が起きてるのか追記してもらえますか？

Comment: 申し訳ないです。copyToRealmOrUpdate()を使うと問題なく動作致しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。大変助かりました！